# Checking if job exists in Quartz.NET randomly fails

Tags: c#, sql-server, quartz.net

When trying to check if a job exists in Quartz.NET, it randomly fails with the following error:

```
Couldn't commit ADO.NET transaction. Transaction not connected, or was disconnected
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
   at Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreSupport.CommitConnection(ConnectionAndTransactionHolder cth, Boolean openNewTransaction) in c:\projects\quartznet\src\Quartz\Impl\AdoJobStore\JobStoreSupport.cs:line 3403
   at Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreSupport.ExecuteInNonManagedTXLock[T](String lockName, Func`2 txCallback, Func`3 txValidator) in c:\projects\quartznet\src\Quartz\Impl\AdoJobStore\JobStoreSupport.cs:line 3562
   at Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX.ExecuteInLock[T](String lockName, Func`2 txCallback) in c:\projects\quartznet\src\Quartz\Impl\AdoJobStore\JobStoreTX.cs:line 76
   at Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreSupport.ExecuteWithoutLock[T](Func`2 txCallback) in c:\projects\quartznet\src\Quartz\Impl\AdoJobStore\JobStoreSupport.cs:line 3418
   at Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreSupport.CheckExists(JobKey jobKey) in c:\projects\quartznet\src\Quartz\Impl\AdoJobStore\JobStoreSupport.cs:line 1739
   at Quartz.Core.QuartzScheduler.CheckExists(JobKey jobKey) in c:\projects\quartznet\src\Quartz\Core\QuartzScheduler.cs:line 1399
   at Quartz.Impl.StdScheduler.CheckExists(JobKey jobKey) in c:\projects\quartznet\src\Quartz\Impl\StdScheduler.cs:line 354
```

And my configuration:

```
        ["quartz.jobStore.type"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz",
        ["quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.SqlServerDelegate, Quartz",
        ["quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix"] = "QRTZ_",
        ["quartz.jobStore.dataSource"] = "rubis",
        ["quartz.dataSource.rubis.connectionStringName"] = "RubisEntities",
        ["quartz.dataSource.rubis.provider"] = "SqlServer-20",
        ["quartz.jobStore.useProperties"] = "true",
        ["quartz.threadPool.threadCount"] = "20"
```

I don't know what I'm missing, and I can't find a situation where it always occurs. It keeps failing randomly.

Comment: Does Quartz this checks from itself or call you some method?

Comment: I call this method in my application

Comment: I guess you use Quartz 2.x and not 3. The line points to a method documentation block, the is code optimized, so its hard to say whats the problem is. It sounds that the connection is closed before the call has ended. Could be a bug in Quartz or some network related connection problems. Just open a [Issue](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/issues) in Github and lets see what the devs say.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that, thanks !

Comment: For information, I tried with Quartz 3 and I randomly get the same error ...

Comment: I finally found my problem, I had the same database for quartz and my entities. I separated the two and now it works perfectly